# Angular 5 - mobile - hide address bar

Tags: mobile, angular5

I have developed an angular 5 web app with the mobild first approach - so responsive and optimized for mobile.
My question now would be what to do in order to hide address bar and so make an icon on screen to start this app (so browser with this app).
Is there a tutorial to do this - I couldn't find some really helpful.